# Странный вид сравнения при правке

Tags: дефект, дизайн, правки

Смотрю я на правку
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/170052
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/674469/revisions

и (помимо прочего) вижу два исправления:

[image: -loca]
[image: -var]

Причём, эти `loca` и `var` - единственное, что показано красным в правой части.

Заглдвыю в сам вопрос (уже отредактированный) - а там всё хорошо:

[image: loca]
[image: var]

Так что же обозначено красным в сравнении ревизий и почему?

Разобрался: это зачёркивание из левого столбца залезает в правый:

[image: скриншот разметки]

Comment: Это так причудливо отображается отрезание пробелов в конце строк. Видимо, связано с тем, что пробелы не вызывают переноса строк и остаются на исходной строке. Интересно, однако.